# Unexpected token at @NgModule

Tags: angular, angular5

Whenever I try running webpack by executing the below command in cmd

```
root-path>node-modules\.bin\webpack
```

I get the below error:

> unexpected token at @NgModule in app.module.ts.

Seems its not recognizing the @ sign.

Start point for my app is main.ts. I am working to create a hybrid app using angular js and angular 5

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.ts';
import { environment } from './environments/environment.ts';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

app.module.ts

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
constructor(private upgrade:UpgradeModule){}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['[config-module]'],{ strictDi: true });
}
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
//const ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      "@angular/upgrade/static": "@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js"
    }
  },
  entry: './src/app/angular6/src/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },


  module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /.ts$/,
        exclude:/(node_modules)/,
        use:{
            loader:"babel-loader",
            options:{
                presets:["env"]
            }
        }

      }

    ]
  }


};
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "lib",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  },
```

Comment: Why are you using babel-loader for ts files?

Comment: I am trying to build angular5 code in my app and run it in angular js framework. I am new to this. can u pls guide if I am going in wrong direction

Comment: Did you use yarn or npm? I had a similar problem. The solution was to clean the yarn cache (`AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache`) and populate it again.